# Click function not working in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JQuery included and all my other click functions work. I have tried to debug and change it from class to ID and both the class and ID name is unique (no other element uses the class or ID).

```
<button type="button" style="margin-left: 5px; padding: 7px;" class="btn query-btn"> Search Transactions </button>
```

Here is my code for the HTML and my JQuery is:

```
 $(".query-btn").click(function () {
            alert("gets here");
 });
```

I literally have no idea why this isn't working because it works on everything else. Could anyone possibly point me the right direction? I have tried giving it an ID (unique) and changing the `.` to a `#` and that does not work either and yes it is wrapped in a:

`$(document).ready(function () {`

I receive no errors which is what is sort of confusing me. Anything would be appreciated!

Note: The HTML button is actually added by AJAX (A button is pressed and the response is directly inserted using the `innerHTML`), not default page load. I'm not sure if this would effect it but just a note incase it does.

Comment: Did you tried your code in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I can't, it uses AJAX. However, the issue has been resolved thanks @VinothKrishnan & Down voters pls comment why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the button is added by Ajax then you need to use `on` and an enclosing selector, roughly:

```
$('body').on('click', '.query-btn', function () {
    // Whatever
});
```

(I'm using `body` as an example selector, ideally you'd scope it to something much smaller.)

Comment: Perfect! Would I be able to find documentation on this? (I am guessing I search for JQuery `on`?) I have never seen this before, I'll mark the answer when I can. Thanks again! - Also, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @KyleE4K It's called event delegation. Have a look at this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Please don't answer such **obvious dupes**, if you cannot add things to it. Close them.

Comment: @Tushar Was on phone; will search for dupe in a few. I'd rather askers had something to work with sooner than later.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, vote to close it. But I wouldn't of made a question if I couldn't find the answer @Tushar Its apparent that I did not know the `on` statement/event existed and everything I searched was literlly silly things like, they forgot to actually import JQuery or use the `$(document).ready` function. But for future reference, I'll try search harder :) Thanks again though!